# 1970's (?) comic, kid's pet lizard turns into giant salamander

Tags: story-identification, comics

Looking for a comic story from the mid 70's (I think) about a kid who is tormented by his building's super. Super ends up throwing the kid's pet lizard into the incinerator/furnace and the lizard turns into a giant, fire-breathing salamander. Last panel is the kid wearing a fire suit and riding the beast. Not much else to go on, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

This story is *[Paying with Fire](https://www.comics.org/issue/75391/#495279)*, first printed in *Secrets of Sinister House* Vol 1 #8, December 1972 issue.

Here's the cover:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX7uv.jpg]

The only difference is that his riding the creature happens at the beginning.